# What is known about Eliyahu from Tishbe?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, eliyahu-hanavi

I am interested in knowing as much as possible about Eliyahu, both from oral and written tradition.

Are there any book(s) and sources that mention something that surely must have been happened but is not mentioned in the Bible?

Comment: Right, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope to see you around.

Comment: Hi Right and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please make sure to take a look at our [tour] so you can get a feel for how this site works. Maybe you’d be interested in all our other questions tagged [tag:Eliyahu-hanavi]? Hope you enjoy the community, and hope to see you around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a book written by [Abie Rotenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abie_Rotenberg) called *Eliyahu Hanavi: The prophet through the prism of Tanach, Talmud and Midrash*

I haven't read it, but it sounds like it would have the information you are looking for. [Available from Artscroll.](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422618233.html)

Comment: Ach, you beat me to it by just a couple of minutes. Just take my upvote and leave. :)

Comment: @DonielF You could always post the same answer a few minutes later and then pretend that you had written it before seeing the other answer, and you'd probably get some upvotes too.

Comment: Geneivas Da’as, much?