# Which Book Should I be Reading to Learn Everything About Eliyahu Hanavi's Teachings?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, eliyahu-hanavi

Which book should I be reading to learn everything about Eliyahu hanavi's teachings? I have Shai Lamoreh, but right now need more depth into his teachings, with extended explanations.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tanna_Debei_Eliyahu_Rabbah.1 and https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tanna_debei_Eliyahu_Zuta%2C_Seder_Eliyahu_Zuta.1

Comment: Melachim would be a good place to start.

Comment: I’d recommend ‘The Theology of Seder Eliahu’. (The author also included an outline of its origin, various editions and commentaries on it.)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94691/what-is-known-about-eliyahu-from-tishbe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is known about Eliyahu from Tishbe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94691/what-is-known-about-eliyahu-from-tishbe)

Answer (score 4):

You could start with this artscroll book: [Eliyahu Hanavi: The prophet through the prism of Tanach, Talmud and Midrash](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/ELIYH.html) by R Avraham Yom Tov Rotenberg which artscroll describes as

> Who was Eliyahu? How can we understand
>   his zealotry? What was his mission? How was he unique? What is his
>   legacy for us? The Sages in the Talmud and Midrashim, the commentators
>   on Tanach, and the classic Torah works are filled with descriptions
>   and discussions about Eliyahu.
>
> In this magnificent volume Avrohom Yom Tov (Abie) Rotenberg scours the
>   classic literature to bring us an unprecedented picture of Eliyahu and
>   his mission. Rabbi Rotenberg cites the verses in Tanach and explains
>   them. And he delves deeper and broadens the portrait based on the
>   major commentators.

Comment: Do you actually have this book? I scanned the pages associated with the link (Table of Contents and sample pages) that you provide and it seems to avoid Tanna D'vei Eliyahu altogether. That was rather surprising since the book is exclusively about Eliyahu HaNavi.

Comment: I saw it and hesitated to buy it. But I have so many *sefarim* on my "waiting pile" that I decided to wait until there is a likely chance that I actually read it

Comment: I hear you. 30,000 and counting... The bigger question is where do you put them? ;-) I have another set of shelves waiting for me to assemble it!!! The seforim live on my other furniture.