# Stories of Eliyahu HaNavi in Gemara

Tags: talmud-gemara, agada-stories-legends, literalism, eliyahu-hanavi

Throughout the Gemara there are many stories in which Eliyahu HaNavi appears in one form or another and is in conversation with Chazal.

Have any commentators or scholars provided a systematic approach to understanding these episodes and what it is Eliyahu HaNavi could represent in these stories or is it to be understood like all Divre Aggada?

(I'm looking for a comprehensive approach but I'll cite a few examples that come to mind, although I'm sure there are far more well known stories than these: Gittin 6b, Taanit 22a, Berakhot 3a, Sanhedrin 98a)

Comment: Maybe [this book](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422618233.html) on this topic is what you seek.

Comment: ↑ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abie_Rotenberg#Writing_career)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108458/which-book-should-i-be-reading-to-learn-everything-about-eliyahu-hanavis-teachi

Comment: Could you give more details on what you consider to be systematic or comprehensive in this regard?

Comment: I feel like looking up the Ben Yoyada in these instances would be insightful.

Comment: There are some academic sources on the subject. Do those interest you?